# Count Down Timer on Resume

Tags: java, android

I'm currently updating an Android application that uses an AsyncTask to do a countdown timer, which isn't stopped onPause or onStop. (The process gets cached by Android, and resumed after the activity is brought back up)

However, I think this could be done in a better way, rather than a AsyncTask. The biggest thing about this timer is that it's not actually resuming from where it was previously -- it needs to act as if it was running the entire time.

Basically what's being done is we have an endtime/date & we subtract the current time from it to get what the counter needs to display.

What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: Have you tried implementing this using a Handler?

Comment: I haven't tried to re-implement it in any form. I've taken over the codebase, and as I've been cleaning things up/bug fixing I've run into this.

Answer (score 1):

If it's something that you need to run periodically, so that it updates your UI, I would use an instance of Timer:
[Android Timer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

The TimerTask that you pass in could be as simple as a private class that overrides the run() method do the time calculations and UI updates.  Just be sure to call cancel() on the Timer object as part of your onPause() method so that its thread gets released, and you can reinitialize it as part of your onResume() method so that it's only running when your app is running.

Hope this gets you started

DSC